# How to generate a list of primes using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: prime-numbers

I've been told it's possible to generate a list of primes using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, will someone show me how?

Comment: Do you know about the Sieve of Erasthotenes?

Comment: I am aware of prime sieves.

Answer (score 3):

I'm at a loss to understand the question, but maybe if I post this answer it will help OP to refine the question.

Start with 2 --- that's a prime.

Add 1, you get 3 --- that's a prime.

Multiply the primes you have so far, and add 1. By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, the new number will have a prime factor, and it can't be any of the primes you already have, so it must be a new one.

So: $2\times3+1=7$ --- that's a prime.

$2\times3\times7+1=43$ --- that's a prime.

$2\times3\times7\times43+1$ isn't a prime, but it has the new prime factor 13 (and also 139, but let's just take the smaller one).

So far, we have the list, $$2, 3, 7, 43, 13,\dots$$ so we have generated a list of primes using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. For the next few terms, see [this entry](http://oeis.org/A000945) at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

If that's not the kind of thing you had in mind, then please clarify.